# Asymptotical behavior of the SIR epidemic model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

The SIR epidemic model presents three differential equations
for three time-dependent variables $s(t), i(t), r(t)$:

$$\begin{align}
 \frac{ds}{dt} & = - \beta i s     \\
 \frac{di}{dt} & = \beta i s - \gamma i  \\
 \frac{dr}{dt} & = \gamma i 
\end{align}$$

It is assumed that the variables are non-negative, $s(t) + i(t) + r(t) = 1$,
and the coefficients $\beta, \gamma$ are positive.
In the literature it is claimed or taken as self-evident that

$$
 \lim_{t \to \infty} i(t) = 0
$$

How can this behavior be proven rigorously?

Comment: Yes, it can. I edited the Wikipedia page about the SIR models to include this. Take a look.

Comment: https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_epid%C3%AAmico#O_Modelo_SIR

Comment: @LucasResende There is no 'rigorous' proof on the mentioned page. Please elaborate the proof here as an answer.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/368299

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that we only need to look at the phase diagram $s\times i$, since $r=1-s-i$. Looking at the phase diagram we will ignore time (different parts of the trajectory will be realized within different velocities), it is possible because the system is autonomous.

First, we need to prove that the system converges to some point, then we'll find the candidates. Let $V(s,i) = s$, we have $\frac{d}{dt}V((s(t), i(t))) = -\beta s(t)i(t) \leq 0$, then, by LaSalle’s theorem:
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} d( (s(t), i(t)), E) = 0$$
where $E = \{ (s,i) : -\beta si = 0 \} = \{ (s,i) : s = 0\text{ or }i=0 \}$.

Now we can study the trajectories and find the exact limit.

Notice that if $\exists t^*$ such that $i(t^*)=0$ or $s(t^*)=0$ we are done. The case $i(t^*) = 0$ has null derivative and the case $s(t^*) = 0$ implies that $i(t)$ has exponential decay.

Since the SEIR is an autonomous system we have, by the implicit function theorem, on the points such that $\frac{ds}{dt} \neq 0$:
$$ \frac{di}{ds} = \frac{ \frac{di}{dt} }{ \frac{ds}{dt} } = \frac{\gamma}{\beta s}-1 \Rightarrow i(s) = \frac{\gamma}{\beta}\ln{\frac{s}{s_0}} - s + i_0 + s_0  $$

We have $\frac{ds}{dt} \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow s> 0\text{ and }i>0$. And it is also true that $s$ is decreasing with $t$ on $s>0$ and $i>0$. So:
$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} i(t) = \inf_{\substack{i>0\\s_0\geq s>0}} \left\{\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\ln{\frac{s}{s_0}} - s + i_0 + s_0 \right\} = 0$$

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} s(t) = \inf \{ s\geq 0 : i(s) \geq 0 \}$$

The inf above is well-defined since $\lim_{s\to 0} i(s) = \lim_{s\to \infty} i(s) = -\infty$ (just for fun: it also has a maximum on $s=\frac{\gamma}{\beta}$, it means that from any starting point with $s> \frac{\gamma}{\beta}$ de infection will grows until $s = \frac{\gamma}{\beta}$ and then starts to decay, when we reach $s\leq \frac{\gamma}{\beta}$ we have the so called "cattle immunity").

Plotting all we've got, we have:

[image: SIR phase diagram]

Comment: Notice that if $s(t),i(t)$ satisfies $i(t)>0$ and $\geq s(t) > 0$ then, since $\frac{ds}{dt} < 0$, we can find $\epsilon,\delta > 0$ such that $s(t+\epsilon) < s(t)-\delta$.

Comment: I am familiar with the expression in curly brackets {...}. But why is inf {...} = 0?

Comment: Just notice that it goes to $-\infty$ as $s\to 0$, but we are limited to $i>0$, so it is trapped on $0$. The only part of the curve that matters is the part inside the domain $i,s > 0$.

Comment: But it is not necessarily $s(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. It can be $s(t) \to s_{\infty} \gt 0$ (strictly positive).

Comment: Of course, but the fact that $i$ can't be negative is what creates that bound $s(t) > s_\infty$.

Comment: The curve $i(s)$, if you look at it for $s\in\mathbb{R}$, goes from $-\infty$ to $i_{max}$ (when $s = \frac{\gamma}{\beta}$) and then decays from $i_{max}$ to $-\infty$ as $s$ grows. But the curve is meaningful only when it is positive and since $s$ is decreasing we are walking from right to left. It means that for some $s>0$, that you called $s_\infty$, we have $i(s) = 0$. But notice that $s_\infty$ attained, it is just the limit as time goes to $\infty$.

Comment: By my first comment. Assume $s_\infty > 0$ and $i_\infty > 0$, then $(s_\infty, i_\infty, 1-s_\infty-i_\infty)$ is not a fixed point. But the system MUST goes to a fixed point.

Comment: Now I got what you are asking. You want to know WHY it must goes to a fixed point. It is the LaSalle's invariance principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle) (or even Lyapunov second method on that case).  Just take $V(t) = -s(t)i(t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It would be very useful if you could extent your answer with the essential arguments in your comments (especially the last three) for future reference. Then, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Edited, hope you enjoy.

Comment: Thanks - accepted. Please correct: $s(t) \to s_\infty$ where $s_\infty \ge 0$ is the solution of $\{...\} = 0$.